# Magento - Cronjob Config - hundreds of cron.php.*** files created constantly

Tags: email, magento, ssh, cron

A few days ago I set up a cronjob for my Magento 1.9.2.1 Webshop and it works - Emails are processed and sent. But when I look into my root folder hundreds of cron.php.*** (like cron.php.96, cron.php.112, and so on) with zero file size are created all the time.

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

This is the command line I put in via PuTTY SSH:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/PATH_TO_MAGENTO/cron.php > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You crontab is indeed totally wrong. What wget is doing is indeed trying to access your cron.php via an http request then saves it to a file.

A proper Magento crontab should be edited via the command `crontab -u apache-user-name -e`, the apache user being something you can find via `ps -o "user group command" -C httpd,apache2`

And should read :

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/your/magento/cron.sh
```

Reference : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron

Comment: I tried `ps -o "user group command" -C httpd,apache2` but I get the following error in PuTTy: 

> ERROR: TTY could not be found


any ideas how to sort this our?

Comment: I also typed in "crontab -u www-data -e" then I get the message "must be privileged to use -u". Any idea what I can do about it? Thx

Comment: You can try to add the cron as root then via `sudo crontab -e` but you need the privileges to do so or to be a sudoer. If not maybe your hosting provider actually as a web interface to add cron job the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it worked out for me:

`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php5.4 -f/path/cron.php`